# How to make a subclass @Entity?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

i'm a new for spring boot.
i found @Entity can make a class to db,and it works.

```
//tTicker.java
@Entity
public class tTicker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private  String currencyPair;
    private  BigDecimal open;
    private  BigDecimal last;

    ......
}

//tTickerRepository.java
public interface tTickerRepository extends CrudRepository<tTicker,Long> {
}    

//tService.java
tTicker tt = new tTicker();
        tt.setCurrencyPair(ticker.getCurrencyPair().toString());
        tt.setOpen(ticker.getOpen());
        tt.setLast(ticker.getLast());      

        ttickerRepository.save(tt);
```

but when i extends this class,only current field store to db.

```
//aTicker.java
@Entity 
public class aTicker extendstTicker {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

}

//tTicker.java
@Entity
public class tTicker {    
    private  String currencyPair;
    private  BigDecimal open;
    private  BigDecimal last;

    ......
}
```

how can i do？ thank you for your help.

https://github.com/xchao0213/aitrader

Comment: I briefly looked into inheritance among entity classes, and it looks non trivial.  Are you sure you need an inheritance hierarchy in your entity classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is related to JPA entities, you should take a look at the JPA documentation (not spring boot).

You need to annotate your super/base class with @MappedSupperClass:

```
//tTicker.java
@MappedSupperClass
public class tTicker {    
    private  String currencyPair;
    private  BigDecimal open;
    private  BigDecimal last;

    ......
}


//aTicker.java
@Entity 
public class aTicker extends tTicker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

}
```

Take a look at @MappedSupperClass documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: @Tim, with MappedSuperclass annotation in tTicker he will achieve what he needs..